# Error suppression within a Proc SQL (SAS)

Tags: hadoop, sas

Connection to Hadoop via SAS-SQL can generate a sas failure if a connection cannot be made. We typically loop a few times to obtain this connection.

Is there a way to suppress the error message for the connection step, but retain for the remainder of the SQL query?

Sas options, including errors=0

Comment: What types of errors? Can you use a LIBNAME statement to make a libref pointing to HADOOP instead?  If so then you can use CONNECT USING syntax to re-use the libref as the source of the connection.  It is probably going to be easier to loop creating a libref as you can do it in a dataset using the LIBNAME() function is stead of the LIBNAME statement.

Comment: Implicit and Explicit through. They are connecting related error messages. We cannot avoid them, but exploring whether they can be suppressed

Comment: Since implicit versus explicit relate to SQL queries your comment makes it sound like the issue is not with making the **connection**.  Instead it sounds like you are getting errors when you try to retrieve or write data to HADOOP.